# tracking athletics exercise time in array

Tags: java, arrays

I am building a java system to record time taken by sport person and store it in an array. The constraint is as follows

1. From Point A to B, departure time is record and Arrival time to point B.
2. From point B departure time is record and Arrival time to point A.
3. Time spend between the points should be calculated
4. The exercise is done 7 days a week.

I only able to figure out how to record one way. How can I track both departure and arrive for every person per day?
Code:

```
public class ArrayLesson {

    static int[] departuretime = new int[7];
    static int sum = 0;
    static double ave = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        departuretime[0] = 07;
        departuretime[1] = 20;
        departuretime[2] = 40;
        departuretime[3] = 12;
        departuretime[4] = 10;
        departuretime[5] = 12;
        departuretime[6] = 11;

        System.out.println("index      Value");//headings
        for (int i = 0; i < departuretime.length; i++) {
            sum = departuretime[i] + sum;
            System.out.printf("%5d%8d%n", i, sum);
        }
        System.out.println("Weekly total:" + sum);
        System.out.println("weekly average:" + sum / departuretime.length);
    }

}
```

Comment: what does the `departuretime[0]` value represent? the time between `A` and `B`?

Comment: the time the athletic left point A.  eg 07:20

Comment: you managed to calculate the sum and average of an array. how does this relate to your question is beyond  me

Comment: if he arrives at point B 30 Minutes later, it should be store as ; 07:50

Comment: should be stored? how??

Comment: @Jack you are supposed to accept answer, if you got solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is my take on the question:

First of all, arrays are not the best data structure here.  Do not use array indexes to represent application-domain data.  Arrays are good for representing **replication of identical items**.  If you need start and end then use "start" and "end" variables, do not use indexes 0 and 1 to represent this.

second, if you need to record and compare date/time, there are built-in java classes to do just that. so use them.  this includes concepts such as duration between times, day-of-week enum, etc

So my solution is as follows

1) create a data structure to hold start-end recording times of one-way.  this is the place to calculate the duration:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

// records start and end times for one direction
public class RecordedTrack {

    public LocalTime start;
    public LocalTime end;

    public RecordedTrack (LocalTime start, LocalTime end) {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    // accept String times in "HH:MM:SS" format 
    public RecordedTrack (String start, String end) {
        this(
            LocalTime.parse(start, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME),
            LocalTime.parse(end, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME));
    }

    public Duration getDuration() {
        return Duration.between(start, end);
    }

    // return String times in "MM:SS" format 
    public String getDurationStr () {
        long seconds = getDuration().getSeconds();
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", (seconds % 3600) / 60, seconds % 60);
    }
}
```

2) create a data structure to hold two-directions complete itinerary:

```
// records start and end times for complete two directions itinerary
public class RecordedItinerary {

    public RecordedTrack AtoB;
    public RecordedTrack BtoA;

    public RecordedItinerary (RecordedTrack AtoB, RecordedTrack BtoA) {
        this.AtoB = AtoB;
        this.BtoA = BtoA;
    }
}
```

3) create a data structure to hold all data related to one person.  I assumed a person has a name to distinguish it from other persons and performs one daily sporting exercise. This can be amended if required:

```
// records weekly itineraries of one person 
public class Person {

    public String name;
    public RecordedItinerary[] weeklyItineraries = new RecordedItinerary[DayOfWeek.values().length+1]; 

    public Person (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // add an itinerary of given day-of-week
    public void addDailyItinerary(DayOfWeek dow, RecordedItinerary itinerary) {
        weeklyItineraries[dow.getValue()] = itinerary;
    }
    // add today's itinerary
    public void addDailyItinerary(RecordedItinerary itinerary) {
        addDailyItinerary(LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfWeek(), itinerary);
    }

    // get an itinerary of given day-of-week 
    public RecordedItinerary getDailyItinerary(DayOfWeek dow) {
        return weeklyItineraries[dow.getValue()];
    }
    // get today's itinerary
    public RecordedItinerary getDailyItinerary() {
        return getDailyItinerary(LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfWeek());
    }

    // a person is identified by his/her name
    // will throw ClassCastException if arg is not a Person
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return this.name.equals(((Person)o).name);
    }
}
```

4) now you can create `Person` instances from your input.  You will need to keep them in a map or whatever data structure you like.  The following is a test program that shows how the system works:

```
public class RecordingTimesSystem {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // new person!
        Person john = new Person("John Doe");
        // add today's two-direction itinerary 
        john.addDailyItinerary(
            new RecordedItinerary(
                new RecordedTrack("07:10:00", "07:20:30"), // a-to-b recorded times
                new RecordedTrack("09:30:00", "09:37:00")) // b-to-a recorded times
        );

        DayOfWeek requestedDayOfWeek = LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfWeek();
        System.out.println(john.name + " " + requestedDayOfWeek.toString() + 
                " AtoB: " + 
                john.getDailyItinerary().AtoB.getDuration().getSeconds() + " (sec) " +  
                john.getDailyItinerary().AtoB.getDurationStr() + " (mm:ss)");
        System.out.println(john.name + " " + requestedDayOfWeek.toString() + 
                " BtoA: " + 
                john.getDailyItinerary().BtoA.getDuration().getSeconds() + " (sec) " +  
                john.getDailyItinerary().BtoA.getDurationStr() + " (mm:ss)");
    }
}
```

output:

```
John Doe SUNDAY AtoB: 630 (sec) 10:30 (mm:ss)
John Doe SUNDAY BtoA: 420 (sec) 07:00 (mm:ss)
```

Comment: this works perfectly well. i like your design concept too.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class, which can have detail of arrival and departure details from A and B point. Then, the object of that class can be stored in `Map` for day 1, 2..7.

```
class SportsPerson
{
   private String sName;  // sports person name.
   private int[][] pointAtoB = new int[1][1]; // arrival and dep for A to B
   private int[][] pointBtoA = new int[1][1]; // arrival and dep for B to A
   // have getter and setter
}
```

Please note, `int` can be `Date` array, which can store complete date and time. But, OP has specified number, in his example.

Now, in you main class, create instance of above class.

```
 Map<Integer,SportsPerson> map = new HashMap<> ();
 SportsPerson person = new SportsPerson ();
 // set values
 map.put (1,person); // 1 represent day 1.
```

**Edited**

As one of my friend asked explanation about using 2D array. Here is the reason.

```
private int[][] pointAtoB = new int[1][1];
```

> From Point A to B, departure time is record and Arrival time to point
>   B.

which means there are two entry for point A to B, in other word start and end time for point A to B. And, 2D array would be best to represent this. (IMO), it can be 1D array as well. But, to represent start and end time, it is best to use two column not a single column.

Comment: why double index arrays? what do the dimensions stand for?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher if you read OP question, he mentioned he needs arrival and departure time for A and B. Then, same again from B to A. Again, this implementation can change as it is independent from main class.

Comment: so? you really think this is immediately evident for all of us? really?? I for one still dont get it

Comment: @SharonBenAsher what you don't get it ?? can you be specific ?

Comment: why do you need 2 dimensions array? what does [0][1] and [1][1] stand for etc

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I don't understand, what is so complex to understand. Just for your clarity, I'm adding more details

Comment: @SharonBenAsher go through my explanation, I'm hoping, you would get understanding, why 2D array.

Comment: no I dont get why you would use 2d array for something so trivial as "two entries for point A to B" so if you needed 3 entries you would create 3D array ? really?? this is good use for multi array in your eyes??

Comment: @SharonBenAsher seriously man ??? you are making me laugh ... what are you understanding.. I really don't get it.. It is clearly mentioned as constraints.. Then, why are you putting your knowledge there.. LOL

Comment: so instead of `int[] pointAtoB = new int[2];` you think int[][] pointAtoB = new int[1][1]; is better? more simple? more what??

Comment: @SharonBenAsher did he mentioned there might more details ?? he clearly mentioned only start and end from point A and B. If his requirement changes, then obvious he can choose to use something else. Don't put your assumption there.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher and why would you think, there can be 3rd entry ?? as per current implementation/use case, he mentioned arrival and departure time, what do you think  3 or 4th time would , is it going to be lunch time ? :D

Comment: @SharonBenAsher,[0][1] means cell value for first row column 1

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Dude, I have alredy mentioned why did I used 2D array instead single 1D array, if you don't read completely and simply jumping into argument. Then I can't help you.

Comment: @Ravi, first of all, it is good design to be extensible.  Second, if 1D array is sufficient, use it.  There should be reason why 1D is not sufficient to go to 2D solution.  thirdly, arrays in general are poor solution for data structures that have app meaning (I will explain in an answer I am writing)

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I know, array is not good solution, but you should also keep in mind, how much OP understand about collection. I can't simply add complex data structure, just because I know.

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I had other solution with combine multiple data structure, which was flexible and handle all scenarios. But, looking at OP question, I understand, he need simple and straight answer.

Comment: I do not see why you would understand that.  OP states he/she are building "java system to record time" and I believe a 1D array is simpler than 2D

Comment: @SharonBenAsher then go ahead post your answer. Also, note that, I'm not saying 1D is complex than 2D. I'm sure, you haven't read my explanation which I edited.

Comment: one more thing - OP states the requirement to hold recording times per person per day.  your map is able to store only one person per day

Comment: @SharonBenAsher  (about ... OP states the requirement to hold recording times per person per day. ) you haven't allowed me to edit my post, you simply jumped into the argument, I don't know whether you had lack of patience or you simply wanted to have an argument.

Comment: there is also a better way in Java to represent days of the week than the numbers 1-7..... shall I go on??

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I'm done with this discussion, please go on and post your answer. I really wanted to know, what you know.